# How to display a lot of data in my windows phone app.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have to display a lot of data in my windows phone app. but when i debug it, i get only a limited amount of data on screen of emulator. The rest gets hidden. Do i need to use some slider option or will it be displayed itself when used in a windows phone? the code is:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="196,54,0,0"    Name="textBlock1" Text="Astro App" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFAE720E" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Image Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="/Astrology;component/Images/Mitra-Chinese-Astrology.png" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBlock 
       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
       Text="The ruling planet for number nine people is Mars. These people are the most humanitarian and generous of all.They have a set of ideals, values and a foresight to visualize the betterment of the people of the society. These people have their own warmth and charisma or fascination. They usually make their impression. These people have high tolerance power and are bless with good imagination, and remarkable creativity. They do not have traces of selfishness store in them, with compassion, kindness, generosity, and humbleness ingrained in their temperament. They are at most of the times self sacrificing and romantic at heart. They can give up their favourites and share it with others as they have immense love for people around them. These people care a lot for people around them. They are distinguished and benevolent people. Adherent to discipline, they are open minded and straight forward in their approach. They amalgamate and orchestrate with everyone. They do not bother for spending their money, their valuable time, and energy if it is spend for the welfare of the society and its people. These people are temperamental, aggressive, and self-assured. They get entangled into the trap of anger and fury. They encounter mood swings. They are shy and unpredictable.  These people are casual and careless with money matters. Lucky Days – Tuesday. Lucky Dates – 9th,18th,27th. Lucky Colours – Red. Lucky Stones – Coral. Lucky Metal – Copper" 
       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
       Margin="6,160,0,0" 
       Grid.Row="1" />
```

Comment: Can you add some code ? What data do you show and how ? What gets hidden ?

Comment: what control do you use to display? and dose this control support data virtualization? show your code

Answer (score 3):

To address this, you can wrap the `TextBlock` inside a `ScrollViewer` - this will allow the user to scroll up and down your text.

However... there is a maximum height in WP7 for any single control - I seem to recall this is 2048 pixels. If your control is taller than this then the bottom part of that control will not be rendered. If this is the case, then you must break your text out into smaller sections and use separate controls.